# Why ML.NET Matrix Factorization uses a regression evaluation?

Tags: ml.net, matrix-factorization

[The example of ML.NET for Matrix Factorization here](https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning-samples/blob/master/samples/csharp/getting-started/MatrixFactorization_ProductRecommendation/ProductRecommender/Program.cs) has no evaluation method for testing the model. It's an `one-class matrix factorization` example, because its trainer option is set to `options.LossFunction = MatrixFactorizationTrainer.LossFunctionType.SquareLossOneClass;`

I searched further and found [another matrix factorization example](https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning-samples/blob/master/samples/csharp/getting-started/MatrixFactorization_MovieRecommendation/MovieRecommendation/Program.cs). Although it's not the `one-class matrixfactorization` but this time it has an evaluation. However the evaluation method is for a regression model. `var metrics = mlcontext.Regression.Evaluate(prediction, labelColumnName: "Label", scoreColumnName: "Score");`

Isn't matrix factorization a class of binary classification? Is it valid to use  regression evaluation for the model? I actually put up this question a few times on the [community chat](https://gitter.im/dotnet/mlnet) for ML.NET but I've got no answers so far. Any comments or answers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The problem that the second example is trying to solve is recommendation, if you look at [line 55](https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning-samples/blob/master/samples/csharp/getting-started/MatrixFactorization_ProductRecommendation/ProductRecommender/Program.cs#L55).

The metrics used for evaluation are the same as the regression metrics, that's why they are being used.

For more examples on Matrix Factorization you can look at the documentation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.ml.trainers.matrixfactorizationtrainer?view=ml-dotnet-preview

https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning/blob/master/docs/samples/Microsoft.ML.Samples/Dynamic/Trainers/Recommendation

Comment: Those two examples are recommendation models. Yes the metrics is for regression model, so it has `RMS`, `Rsquared` and etc. What I'm asking is that why they used `Regression` evaluation method on a recommendation model while the recommendation is a class of `binary classification` ( I'm not sure this is true or not though )

Comment: it can be binary classification, if your label is binary(like/dislike), or it can be regression, if your label is the number of stars rating a product. 
https://www.quora.com/How-exactly-is-machine-learning-used-in-recommendation-engines